# Getting two database models to show on one html page

Tags: python, django

Currently working on a web page and I want to show two different tables of information one is for individual foods and the other is for recipes, however I can only get the first class to pull up any information I've tested to see if the first class can pull up the recipe database and it, in fact, currently out of ideas on what to try next.

```
class SearchFoodResultsView(ListView):
    model = Food
    template_name = 'nutrihacker/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'food_list'




    # overrides ListView get_queryset to find names containing search term and pass them to template
    def get_queryset(self):

        query = self.request.GET.get('term')
        if (query == None):
            return Food.objects.all()
        else: # If there are any foods containing the query, they will be in the resulting object_list which is used by search.html in a for loop
            food_list = Food.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains = query)
            )


            return food_list


class SearchRecipeResultsView(ListView):
    model = RecipePreset
    template_name = 'nutrihacker/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'recipe_list'

    # overrides ListView get_queryset to find names containing search term and pass them to template
    def get_queryset(self):

        query = self.request.GET.get('term')
        if (query == None):
            return RecipePreset.objects.all()
        else: # If there are any recipes containing the query, they will be in the resulting object_list which is used by search.html in a for loop
            recipe_list = RecipePreset.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains = query)
            )


            return recipe_list
```

Comment: Update: so I partially answered my question turns out that I cant call the same url path twice since django will always go with the first one that it sees so the class SearchRecipeResultsView is never looked at which leaves me with another dilemma in how do I call the get_queryset twice in one class?